# Angular ng-click not working on IE 11 when inside of a wrapper div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a grid, which is generated by `ng-repeat`. In the generated grid elements, there is an `ng-click` directive, which doesn't trigger on IE11, but works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

What I also found was that when I "right-click -> Inspect Element" on the grid elements, the wrapper `div` gets selected as the one to be inspected, instead of the specific grid element that I right-clicked. My guess is that somehow the wrapper `div` is considered to be "over" the grid elements. However, even when I set the `z-index` of the grid elements to 9999999, the situation is the same - the clicks don't get registered at all.

The layout code is as follows:

```
<div id="gridHolder">                           <!-- wrapper div -->
  <div class="hex-row" ng-repeat="row in grid.data">
      <div class="hex center"                   <!-- grid elements -->
           ng-if="selectedClient.detailedtiles"
           ng-repeat="col in row"
           ng-class="hexClass(col)" ng-class-even="'even'">

            <div class="score" ng-click="plots(col)">    <!-- this doesn't work -->
                <span>{{ col.score }}</span>
                <div ng-class="{'arrowUp': col.tendency == 'rising'}"></div>
                <div ng-class="{'arrowDown': col.tendency == 'falling'}"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ktScore"></div>
            <div class="vsScore" ng-click="improvement(col)"></div>    <!-- this doesn't work -->
            <div class="serviceName">{{ col.name }}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="hex center simple"            <!-- grid elements -->
           ng-if="!selectedClient.detailedtiles"
           ng-repeat="col in row"
           ng-class="hexClass(col)" ng-class-even="'even'"
           ng-click="plots(col)">               <!-- this doesn't work -->

            <div class="score" >
                <span>{{ col.score }}</span>
                <div ng-class="{'arrowUp': col.tendency == 'rising'}"></div>
                <div ng-class="{'arrowDown': col.tendency == 'falling'}"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="serviceName">{{ col.name }}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What could be the cause of this? How can I propagate the click event down to the child elements if IE considers the wrapper to be "over" the grid elements?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing what might be similar behavior.

Comment: No, I am starting a bounty on this one. Still a problem.

Comment: Can you post a plunkr?

Comment: Could be related to css classes. Can you post them too?

Comment: here is a little plunkr that works fine in ie11.  can you update it with your specifics?  http://plnkr.co/edit/nda5D6qhLv9xuPbakcmd?p=preview

Comment: Here is the plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/BZqKHYcgeeaf7kSAByjY?p=preview. It seems that it's almost definitely a CSS problem, but I am not completely sure whether the Plunkr is entirely representative of the real problem. In the actual project, clicks work on Firefox, Chrome, while in the Plunkr they don't work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `pointer-events: none;` from the `.hex` class.

`pointer-events: none;` prevents all clicking on the element.

Forked plunker with pointer-events removed: http://plnkr.co/edit/LPVlsPPeqFzaxGG96jel?p=preview

Please [read here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/) to learn more about pointer-events in CSS.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work. Will ask the testers to test the solution, and if everything is fine, I will award you the bounty :)